# how can I fix the ECONNREFUSED proxy error?

Tags: proxy, npm-start

I used 'npm start' to open it in the browser but I keep getting this:

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /board from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
I am not sure what this means or how to fix it.